# Xlsx library will not load properly in R

Tags: r, xlsx

I installed the xlsx package in R, but when I tried to load the library I got the following message:

```
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
```

The Mac is version 10.14.1 Mojave. R is version 3.5.1. Java version is 1.8.0_73. Java and Mac are both 64 bits as I saw that as an issue with other question submissions. Is this a problem related to the newest macOS Mojave?

Comment: If you are not required to use the package try: install.packages("readxl")